# No popup for Site Analytics graphs?

Tags: bug, design, site-analytics

I've been using the [site analytics privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) recently, in an effort to compare some data. When hovering over the Posts graph, I can get a popup with specific data on the plot:

[image: Posts popup]

But for the votes and traffic graphs, there's no popups:

[image]

Is this intentional? With some of these graphs covering more than 5k per y-series point, it can get rather difficult to read.

Comment: I think you took the freehand circles a little overboard there... excellent.

Comment: It's usually 25k, 5k only on beta sites (moderators probably have it automatically regardless of rep anyway) - I just removed it to avoid confusing people, linking to the page instead.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, that's right.